# R: Best fit for data (Exponential or Power), with curve predicted beyond final data point

Tags: r, function, curve-fitting, exponential

So, I am challenged and request a little guidance.

I have used the rriskDistributions package to evaluate some CDFs for some industrial sector injury data with the get.lnorm.par() function. It fits the data great, unfortunately, the axes require swapping because my response variable is currently on the x-axis, and needs to be on the y-axis. Unfortunately again, the get.lnorm.par() function requires that the probabilities be only on the y-axis, and I cannot figure out how to create the same curve with swapped axes.

I want to get it to look something like this:
[image: Exponential or Power fit curve, quant as response to prob]

An example of the code that I have worked through in ggplot follows:

```
x <- c(0.0416988,0.0656371,0.1015444,0.1270270,0.1536680,0.1694981,0.2509653)
y <- c(3170221,6810103,14999840,26623982,48903587,74177290,266181110)
prob <- c(x) ## There are 389 different x values, but keeping it simple!
quant <- c(y) ## Same as x.    
df1 <- data.frame(prob,quant)
plot2 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=prob, y=quant)) + geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm", formula= log(y)~x, se=FALSE) + 
    labs(y="quantiles", x="probabilities", title="Probs vs Quants") 
plot2
```

I have created lines that fit this data, but everything ends at the last data point.

When I used get.lnorm.par(), the fit was great, but like stated previously, the axes require flipping. When I tried this, I continued to get errors about infinite output and could not define the bounds of the function to be plotted.

So, here is the code using the rriskDistributions package:

```
pct <- c(0.0416988,0.0656371,0.1015444,0.1270270,0.1536680,0.1694981,0.2509653)
my.lnorm<-get.lnorm.par(p=pct, q=c(3170221,6810103,14999840,26623982,48903587,74177290,266181110), 
                    tol = 0.001, scaleX = c(0,0.0809))
```

Essentially, I am trying to create a fit curve for the data (either exponential or power) that expands, or predicts beyond the final data point. This I cannot figure out for the life of me, and changing any of the parameters in the rriskDistributions functions is quite challenging.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: But doesn't the fit give you the parameters of the log-normal distribution? So if you plot the [corresponding CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) that should fit your x(y)

Comment: The get.lnorm.par() gives me meanlog and sdlog of the fit function when the data is plotted for Y-axis = prob, and X-axis = quant. I imagine that I could use that somehow to flip the CDF axes and plot, but I do not know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, there you have it. I have to say that the documentation of rrisk thing is a catastrophy but maybe [this](http://datavisualizationineconomics.blogspot.de/2013/01/normal-vs-lognormal-distribution-using-r.html) helps?